# Why second is relation is affecting the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given relations R(a,b) and S(c,d).I execute following query

select a,b from R,S;

When S is empty, result is always empty while R(a,b) is non empty.I am not getting how S is affecting the query even there should be no interaction with S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, *regardless* of the items you're selecting from the query, you're *still* doing a join between the two tables.

If `S` is empty, the result of the join is zero rows because that's what the join gives you. That is indeed what you're seeing.

If `S` had 10,000 rows you would get that many copies of each row in `R`.

The *only* way you'll see the correct number of rows from `R` (assuming no `where` clause affecting the join), is if `S` had exactly one row in it.

If you're not using any columns in `S` for the query, you really shouldn't be listing it as a source table. The correct query would be:

```
select a, b from R
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting how S is affecting the query even there should be no interaction with S

Because the **Cartesian product of A and the empty set is an empty set**. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set

Also, check this [Why is the Cartesian product of a set A and empty set an empty set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305766/why-is-the-cartesian-product-of-a-set-a-and-empty-set-an-empty-set)